# dereference a pointer to a pointer casted from array pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Learning C and this confusing me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int m[5][5];
    int count = 0;                                                                                                         
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){                                                                                                    
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            m[i][j] = count++;
        }
    }                                                                                                                     
    int **p = m;                                                                                                          
    int (*k)[5] = m;                                                                                                      
    printf("%p\t%p\t%p", *p, *k, *m);                                                                                     
    return 0;
}
```

that's what has been printed:
`0x100000000     0x7ffff1fc9d70  0x7ffff1fc9d70`

I'm really confused why dereference *p is `0x100000000`, shouldn't it be `0x7ffff1fc9d70`?

Comment: Why is `int **p = m;` ? This means `p` is a pointer to another pointer to integer!

Comment: Turn your compiler warnings on or to a higher level. `int **p = m;` should give you one.

Comment: Actually, it’s a good idea to keep your compiler warnings maxed out all the time. As a learner, they’ll alert you to things you don’t understand; when writing production code, they’ll alert you to potential problems.

Comment: gcc actually gave me an warning of incompatible pointer type, I just ignored it though. what was in my mind then is that `int m[5][5]` should be a pointer to pointer. I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You’re thinking that `m` is of type `int **`, right?

It’s not. If you had done this, it would be:

```
int *m[5];
```

That make an array of five pointers to int, so `m` would be pointer to pointer to int.

However, if you do this:

```
int m[5][5];
```

You get enough space for 25 ints, which the compiler will access as a 5x5 two-dimensional array. `p` points to the beginning of that array. Dereference it, and the compiler reads the beginning of that array and interprets it as a pointer to int. Change the numbers you’re filling it with, and you’ll get different pseudo-pointers.

Comment: I kinda grasp it. I do change the value to 200 in m[0][0] and it prints out 200. I searched for how 2D array stores in memory, is m actually a pointer to an array of size five or is m a pointer to an array of size 25?

Comment: Now I think I get it after re-reading your answer. m is actually a type of int*[5] and it points to is the beginning of the array. So if modify `int **p` to `int *p` and then dereference p, I would get the result of m[0][0]. Is that correct?

Comment: `m` is a pointer to an array of 5 elements. Each of those elements is an array of 5 ints. The total size is 5, times 5, times the size of an int. For your second question, I would urge you to experiment and find out for yourself. Also, see this: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.2.1

Comment: I'll try it out. Thanks a lot!